# Find the convergence radius for $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k(z+i)^{2k}}{2^k} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

What's the convergence radius for

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k(z+i)^{2k}}{2^k} $$

I using the root criterium that says that the serie convergence if the limit is 0.

$$ lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{k(z+i)^{2k}}{2^k} \right)^{1/k}$$

So  this tells me that if $z+i < 1$ I should have convergence. So my answer would be $z = |1-i| = \sqrt{2}$.

However the answer should be $|z+i| < \sqrt{2}$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the root criterion we get

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}  \left|\frac{k(z+i)^{2k}}{2^k} \right|^{1/k}=\frac{|z+i|^2}{2}<1\iff |z+i|<\sqrt 2$$

Comment: Beat me to it...